# Multiple form fields with same 'name' attribute not posting

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, mootools

I'm dealing with some legacy HTML/JavaScript. Some of which I have control over, some of which is generated from a place over which I have no control.

There is a dynamically generated form with hidden fields. The form itself is generated via a Velocity template (Percussion Rhythmyx CMS) and JavaScript inserts additional hidden form fields. The end result is hidden form fields generated with the same 'name' attribute. The data is being POSTed to Java/JSP server-side code about which I know very little.

I know that form fields sharing the same 'name' attribute is valid. For some reason the POSTed data is not being recognized the back end. **When I examine the POST string, the same-name-keys all contain no data.**

If I manipulate the code in my dev environment such that only a single input field exists for a given name, the data IS POSTed to the back end correctly. The problem is not consistent, sometimes, it works just fine.

Is there something I can do to guarantee that the data will be POSTed?  Can anyone think of a reason why it would not be?

```
I should really update my answer and post code here, because POST requests without 
variable strings indicates the problem is on the client side.
```

Comment: If it's really just a simple form POST, then unless the JavaScript code is disabling the inputs they'd be posted. You can use a Firefox plugin like TamperData to look at the actual HTTP request from the browser's point of view.

Comment: When you submit a form using the POST method, the fields are passed using a variable name specified by the 'name' attribute of the item. If two items have the same name, they are attempting to store data in the same variable, so the data will get reassigned. It's the same as if you did `item1 = 'hello'; item1 = 'world';`...in the end, item1 will be 'world'. In your case, perhaps the last assignment to the variable is a blank value.

Comment: @Travesty3 It completely depends on the server code. He said that the server code here is Java/JSP, and the Java runtime will provide an *array* of values when there are repeated parameter names.  The values won't be "reassigned".

Comment: How exactly are you "examining" the POST data?

Comment: @Pointy: My apologies, not familiar with how JSP works. I'm more of a PHP guy, so I assumed it was the same.

Comment: @Travesty3 well I didn't mean to attack you or anything, just trying to keep the information "clean" for posterity :-)  Java/JSP is a strange brutal world, but it does do some things well ...

Comment: @Pointy : Examining POST data via the 'Net' tab in Firebug.

Comment: So this code has *never* worked?  I mean, I know that browsers do actually send form elements to the server. Have you checked to make sure that the HTML is really valid?  Like, that the form element really does enclose all the inputs?

Comment: @Pointy : It's actually worse than that.  It sometimes works. :-)  The HTML is valid, I've checked.  This whole scheme is keyed off of the MooTools DOMREADY event.  When DOMREADY fires, the legacy JS inserts the extra hidden form fields.  But if a user submits the form before DOMREADY, the extra fields are not there yet and the data is successfully POSTED. - There's a whole other problem tied into this, in that the page structure is inherently flawed such that it allows this situation to exist in the first place.  But that gets into modifying the JSP code, then releasing to prod, etc...

Comment: @BobFiveThousand Maybe you could have the MooTools "ready" handler freeze the page by putting up a transparent `<div>` that covers the whole page, and intercepts clicks etc. Or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked out a brute-force solution.  Note that I'm pretty aware this is a hack. But I'm stuck in the position of having to work around other code that I have no control over.

Basically, I've created an ONSUBMIT handler which examines the form for the repeated hidden fields and makes sure they are all populated with the correct data.  This seems to guarantee that the POST string contains data regardless of how the form gets rendered and the Java back end appears to be happy with it as well.

I've tested this in the following situations:

1. Code generates single instances of the hidden fields (which does happen sometimes)
2. Code generates multiple instances of the hidden fields
3. Code generates no instances of the hidden fields (which *should* never happen, but hey...)

My 'else' condition contains a tiny bit of MooTools magic, but it's otherwise straight-forward stuff.

Maybe someone else will find this useful one day...

Thanks for the help!

```
<form method="post" name="loginform" id="loginform" action="/login" onsubmit="buildDeviceFP(this);">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function insertFieldValues( fields, sValue )
        {
            if ( 'length' in fields ) 
            {
                // We got a collection of form fields
                for ( var x = 0; x < fields.length; x++ ) {
                    fields[x].value = sValue;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // We got a single form field
                fields.value = sValue;
            }
        }

        function buildDeviceFP( oForm )
        {
            // Get the element collections for Device Fingerprint & Language input fields from the form.
            var devicePrintElmts = oForm.elements.deviceprint;
            var languageElmts    = oForm.elements.language;

            // 'devicePrintElmts' & 'languageElmts' *should* always exist.  But just in case they don't...
            if ( devicePrintElmts) {
                insertFieldValues( devicePrintElmts, getFingerprint() );
            } else if ( oForm.deviceprint ) {
                oForm.deviceprint.value = getFingerprint();
            } else {
                $('logonbox').adopt(
                    new Element( 'input', {'type':'hidden', 'name':'deviceprint', 'value':getFingerprint()} )
                );
            }

            if ( languageElmts) {
                insertFieldValues( languageElmts, getLanguage() );
            } else if ( oForm.language ) {
                oForm.language.value = getLanguage();
            } else {
                $('logonbox').adopt(
                    new Element( 'input', {'type':'hidden', 'name':'language', 'value':getLanguage()} )
                );
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    function disableBlankValues()
    {
        var elements = document.getElementById("form1").elements;
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
        {
            if (elements[i].value == "")
                elements[i].disabled = true;
        }
    }
</script>

<form action="page.php" method="POST" onsubmit="disableBlankValues()" id="form1">
    <input type="hidden" name="field1" value="This is field 1."/>
    <input type="hidden" name="field1" value=""/>
</form>
```

---

**EDIT**

I now realize the actual problem (multiple variables with the same name should be passed to JSP as an array) and my solution is probably not what the OP is looking for, but I'm leaving it here just in case it happens to help someone else who stumbles upon this post.

Answer (score 0):

you could use something like:

```
var form = document.getElementById('yourformid');
var elements = form.getElementsByName('repeatedName');
var count = 0;
for(var item in elements){
   elements[item].name += count++;
}
```

this way you will get each hiddenfield with the names:

```
name0
name1
name2
...
```

Comment: Should not be necessary as the server-side code will present an array of values for repeated parameter names in the HTTP request.

Comment: yes it should not, but for some reason, this is what he asked for

Comment: @AndréAlçadaPadez : No, that's not what I asked for at all.  Although I appreciate the effort.  :-)

Comment: "Is there something I can do to guarantee that the data will be POSTed?" - i think at least this part is covered :)

Comment: @AndréAlçadaPadez : I haven't tested this solution, but I'm assuming it does technically do the job of ensuring the data gets POSTed.  It's simple enough code.  But it does so by changing the `name` attribute.  Which would require a modification of the server-side Java code.  Which would, in turn, require a major release to the production server.  All of which _should_ be unnecessary because the generated HTML is valid.

Comment: ok, you are right, i was assuming you have tried everything, i thought of an unorthodox workaround...

Comment: @AndréAlçadaPadez : Hey, no prob.  I'm happy someone took the time to look into it.